# How to get all inner texts of tag by XPATH?

Tags: xpath

Is it possible to get all inner texts of some tag by `XPath`?

For example, in one case, there could be text: `root.xpath('//h2[text()="Description"]/following-sibling::p/span/span/text())`

In another case, it could be in first `span`: `root.xpath('//h2[text()="Description"]/following-sibling::p/span/text())`

So my question is, whether is there some way how to get all texts in one tag but not only on first level.

Something like `root.xpath('//h2[text()="Description"]/following-sibling::p/*/text())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `//` axis ?

```
//h2[text()="Description"]/following-sibling::p/span//text()
```

This should return all text nodes, anywhere within the `span`